# How to do server side programming

Tags: node.js, websocket, server-side

I'm trying to design a system with linux server with a webUI. The webUI will communicate with the server using websockets (node.js). How would I control a linux script from this webUI using sockets. There are two script running on the server, one for writing a file and other for making sure there is enough free space on the RAID0. How would I connect these script to the webUI using sockets. Should I write a new program in python or C++ to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Since its a bash script you should use the 
[child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to execute it and handle its execution.

You can then send information back to client when events are triggered to inform about the process execution state.